# Hihglight duplicate cells from two different sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight duplicate cells of **Column A** in **sheet 1** by matching **Column A** in **sheet 2**. I used this formula in conditional formatting in sheet 1.

```
=countif(INDIRECT("2!A:A"),A1)>1
```

But it not working.

In sheet 1 Column A has these items

[image]

In sheet 2 Column A has these items

[image]

Here is the formula

[image]

Here is the [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19aJQiYkDcgQdMn7P2szA6nGrbr3j7PLnA5vRFla2--4/edit#gid=896686168)

I check other links, but couldn't complete the task. So I am posting a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula should be:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("2!A:A"),A1)>0
```

[image: 0]